# Laravel 5 PHPUnit test fails with getContent() on null

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, phpunit

I'm getting an error when I want to run a PHPUnit test on my Laravel 5 website. Can you give me a hint? Already updated both composer and phpunit package.

```
PHPUnit 5.2.12 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Starting test 'Warning'.
W
Starting test 'ExampleTest::testEncryptionIsIntelligent'.
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getContent() on null in /var/www/hu.testsite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/InteractsWithPages.php on line 187


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Call to a member function getContent() on null
```

Here is my test file:

```
<?

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * My test implementation
     */
    public function testEncryptionIsIntelligent()
    {
        $this->see('Laravel 5');
        $this->visit('/');
        $this->visit('/auth/login');
        $this->type('test.admin@testsite.hu', 'email');
        $this->type('test', 'password');
        $this->press('');
        $this->seePageIs('/admin');
        $this->see('Welcome to the dashboard');
        $this->visit('/');
    }
}
```

And here are the composer packages installed:

```
barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver    v0.1.4  A Flysystem Driver for elFinder
barryvdh/laravel-debugbar             v2.2.0  PHP Debugbar integration for Laravel
barryvdh/laravel-elfinder             v0.3.6  A Laravel Package to integrate elFinder 2
behat/behat                           v3.0.15 Scenario-oriented BDD framework for PHP 5.3
behat/gherkin                         v4.4.1  Gherkin DSL parser for PHP 5.3
behat/mink                            v1.7.1  Browser controller/emulator abstraction for PHP
behat/mink-browserkit-driver          v1.3.2  Symfony2 BrowserKit driver for Mink framework
behat/mink-extension                  v2.2    Mink extension for Behat
behat/mink-goutte-driver              v1.2.1  Goutte driver for Mink framework
behat/mink-selenium2-driver           v1.3.1  Selenium2 (WebDriver) driver for Mink framework
behat/transliterator                  v1.1.0  String transliterator
classpreloader/classpreloader         3.0.0   Helps class loading performance by generating a single PHP file containing all of the autoloaded files for a specific use case
danielstjules/stringy                 1.10.0  A string manipulation library with multibyte support
davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs   3.0.0   A simple Laravel-style way to create breadcrumbs in Laravel 4+.
dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir              0.1     implementation of xdg base directory specification for php
doctrine/inflector                    v1.1.0  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                 1.0.5   A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
fabpot/goutte                         v3.1.2  A simple PHP Web Scraper
fzaninotto/faker                      v1.5.0  Faker is a PHP library that generates fake data for you.
greggilbert/recaptcha                 2.1.1   reCAPTCHA Validator for Laravel 5
guzzlehttp/guzzle                     6.2.0   Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library
guzzlehttp/promises                   1.1.0   Guzzle promises library
guzzlehttp/psr7                       1.2.3   PSR-7 message implementation
hamcrest/hamcrest-php                 v1.2.2  This is the PHP port of Hamcrest Matchers
illuminate/html                       v5.0.0  
instaclick/php-webdriver              1.4.3   PHP WebDriver for Selenium 2
intervention/image                    2.3.6   Image handling and manipulation library with support for Laravel integration
jakub-onderka/php-console-color       0.1     
jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter v0.3.2  
jeremeamia/SuperClosure               2.2.0   Serialize Closure objects, including their context and binding
laracasts/behat-laravel-extension     1.0     Laravel extension for Behat
laravel/framework                     v5.1.31 The Laravel Framework.
league/flysystem                      1.0.20  Filesystem abstraction: Many filesystems, one API.
maatwebsite/excel                     v2.1.2  An eloquent way of importing and exporting Excel and CSV in Laravel 4 with the power of PHPExcel
maximebf/debugbar                     v1.11.1 Debug bar in the browser for php application
mockery/mockery                       0.9.4   Mockery is a simple yet flexible PHP mock object framework for use in unit testing with PHPUnit, PHPSpec or any other testing...
monolog/monolog                       1.18.1  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
mtdowling/cron-expression             v1.1.0  CRON for PHP: Calculate the next or previous run date and determine if a CRON expression is due
myclabs/deep-copy                     1.5.0   Create deep copies (clones) of your objects
nesbot/carbon                         1.21.0  A simple API extension for DateTime.
nikic/php-parser                      v2.0.1  A PHP parser written in PHP
paragonie/random_compat               v1.4.1  PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock     2.0.4   
phpoffice/phpexcel                    1.8.1   PHPExcel - OpenXML - Read, Create and Write Spreadsheet documents in PHP - Spreadsheet engine
phpspec/php-diff                      v1.0.2  A comprehensive library for generating differences between two hashable objects (strings or arrays).
phpspec/phpspec                       2.5.0   Specification-oriented BDD framework for PHP 5.3+
phpspec/prophecy                      v1.6.0  Highly opinionated mocking framework for PHP 5.3+
phpunit/php-code-coverage             3.3.0   Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage information.
phpunit/php-file-iterator             1.4.1   FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-text-template             1.2.1   Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                     1.0.7   Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream              1.4.8   Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
phpunit/phpunit                       5.2.12  The PHP Unit Testing framework.
phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects          3.1.0   Mock Object library for PHPUnit
psr/http-message                      1.0     Common interface for HTTP messages
psr/log                               1.0.0   Common interface for logging libraries
psy/psysh                             v0.7.2  An interactive shell for modern PHP.
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup    1.0.0   Looks up which function or method a line of code belongs to
sebastian/comparator                  1.2.0   Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/diff                        1.4.1   Diff implementation
sebastian/environment                 1.3.5   Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                    1.2.1   Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state                1.1.1   Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/recursion-context           1.0.2   Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/resource-operations         1.0.0   Provides a list of PHP built-in functions that operate on resources
sebastian/version                     1.0.6   Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP projects
studio-42/elfinder                    2.1.9   File manager for web
swiftmailer/swiftmailer               v5.4.1  Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/browser-kit                   v2.8.3  Symfony BrowserKit Component
symfony/class-loader                  v2.8.3  Symfony ClassLoader Component
symfony/config                        v2.8.3  Symfony Config Component
symfony/console                       v2.7.10 Symfony Console Component
symfony/css-selector                  v2.7.10 Symfony CssSelector Component
symfony/debug                         v2.7.10 Symfony Debug Component
symfony/dependency-injection          v2.8.3  Symfony DependencyInjection Component
symfony/dom-crawler                   v2.7.10 Symfony DomCrawler Component
symfony/event-dispatcher              v2.8.3  Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/filesystem                    v3.0.3  Symfony Filesystem Component
symfony/finder                        v2.7.10 Symfony Finder Component
symfony/http-foundation               v2.7.10 Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                   v2.7.10 Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/polyfill-apcu                 v1.1.1  Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php56                v1.1.1  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util                 v1.1.1  Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/process                       v2.7.10 Symfony Process Component
symfony/routing                       v2.7.10 Symfony Routing Component
symfony/translation                   v2.7.10 Symfony Translation Component
symfony/var-dumper                    v2.7.10 Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables
symfony/yaml                          v2.8.3  Symfony Yaml Component
tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles     1.5.5   CssToInlineStyles is a class that enables you to convert HTML-pages/files into HTML-pages/files with inline styles. This is v...
vlucas/phpdotenv                      v1.1.1  Loads environment variables from `.env` to `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` automagically.
watson/sitemap                        2.0.12  Generate Google Sitemaps in Laravel 4/5
```

And help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$this->see('Laravel 5');
$this->visit('/');
```

to

```
$this->visit('/')
     ->see('Laravel 5');
```

You are trying to first check for something that laravel is unaware of where to check for. First visit a page and then check for the content.

I would chain the lines as follows:

```
    $this->visit('/')
         ->see('Laravel 5')
         ->visit('/auth/login')
         ->type('test.admin@testsite.hu', 'email')
         ->type('test', 'password')
         ->press('')
         ->seePageIs('/admin')
         ->visit('/')
         ->see('Welcome to the dashboard');
```

Comment: Thank you, it brought me closer to the answer, but not fully. Now I'm getting the following error:

http://pastebin.com/60WH7SmW

Comment: Can you post this to the question?

Comment: Can you paste the whole ExampleTest file?

Comment: Erm.. Do I need that? :D

Comment: How are you running the test?

Comment: Okay, in your TestCase.php file, change the class declaration to this:  `abstract class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`

Comment: I suggest you ask this as a new question.

Comment: OK, I'll do that. Thank you